# Open Source user-friendly peer-to-peer sync? (like BitTorrent Sync)

Tags: open-source, file-synchronization

I just left Dropbox due to privacy concerns, and started using [BitTorrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync) which I already love.

While I wish BitTorrent Sync becomes hugely successful, I am also wondering whether there is any Open Source equivalent?

I know [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) and [unison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unison%5f%28file%5fsynchronizer%29), but they miss the QR code UI that makes it so easy to share secrets between smartphones.

Requirement:

- Sync folders, handle conflicts
- Peer-to-peer
- Peers are found automagically, especially when on the same network, or by using smart tricks, preferably without a central server
- Easy folder addition with QR code
- Run on Linux/Mac/Windows/Android/iOS or at least Linux/Android

Not present in BitTorrent Sync, but bonus for:

- Ubuntu indicator showing whether up-to-date, and providing an easy way to open the UI.

Non-mobile UI can be a local web server or native, but I am OK with command-line in early stages of development.

Comment: I don't know about peer-to-peer, but there are plenty of open source Dropbox replacements like [Owncloud](https://owncloud.org/). But maybe you're looking for something like [Freenet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freenet)? If yes, I'll happily expand to an answer.

Comment: Peer-to-peer is a central requirement, so Owncloud is not a valid solution. Freenet sounds like it might be a valid solution.

Comment: I'm just realising Freenet is maybe not the right thing if you want to host data that is only accessible to you

Comment: Also looking for something like this ever since BTsync 2.0 came out - all sorts of BS with identities, links, and subscriptions turned a good product into crapware - my best alternative so far has been mapping a local folder on  my phone (ES file explorer for android, im sure there are others) and just placing a file with the secret key there for easy phone access

Comment: I do know that it doesn't answer your question, but this does address your concerns - https://spideroak.com/ - like DropBox except that it encrypts at your PC before transmitting. You can also create shared "rooms" See https://spideroak.com/user-manual/spideroak-share/ for more. HTH

Comment: @Mawg: SpiderOak is not peer-to-peer sync: It uses a central (self-hosted) server.

Comment: Yup, I know that - technically it do0esn't answer your question, but I just thought it might help you to know that there is something that answers the spirit of your question. It is end to end encrypted, cannot be decrypted by the SpiderOak company, and you can share with your peers. Since you haven't received an answer, you might want to consider it as an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) is a file synchronization program which is:

- 100% peer-to-peer (decentralized, no central server needed)
- Open source
- Runs on Android, Windows, Linux, Mac, BSD, Solaris

[image: syncthing web UI]

An [Ubuntu indicator](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/09/syncthing-gui-gtk3-python-gui-ubuntu-ppa.html) is available, it also integrates in the file manager (Nautilus, Nemo and Caja).

It does handle QR codes.

Comment: merci de la recommendation, ca marche pile poil. Domo arigatu !

Comment: Syncthing supports QR-codes for quite a while now... and the "Ubuntu indicator" (`syncthing-gtk`) integrates also in the file manager (Nautilus, Nemo and Caja).

Comment: @DJCrashdummy: I edited to include your feedback, is it correct? Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: well... `syncthing-gtk` is not just an - like you resp. the OP call it - "Ubuntu indicator", it is a cross-platform GUI with all the features of the WebGUI plus [some additional](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing-gtk#additional-features) like filesystem-watching/instant-sync, desktop-notifications, filemanager-integration for `nautilus`, `nemo` & `caja`, etc. - the updates in the article/link (which is good, because they provide the advised debs/ppa by the devs) you provide also sum it up pretty good.